# How to Update multiple field including push into an existing array in NodeJs mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, multer

This is my product Schema using mongoose in nodeJs. However I am developing a REST API.

```js
const ImageSchema = new Schema({ 
    path: {
        type: String
    },
    pos: {
        type: Number
    }
});

const ProductSchema = new Schema({  
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Product title is required.']
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    created_date: {
        type: Date ,
        required: [true, 'Created Time required.'],
        default: Date.now
    },
    images: [
        ImageSchema
    ]
});

const Product = mongoose.model('product', ProductSchema);

module.exports = Product;
```

This is how I update a product

```js
router.put('/:id', upload.single('pImg'), function(req, res, next){  
    var x = req.body;  

    Product.findByIdAndUpdate({
        _id: req.params.id
    }, x).then(function(){
        Product.findOne({
            _id: req.params.id
        }).then(function(product){
            res.send(product);
        });
    }).catch(next); 
});
```

My question is how can I push into the images array and also update other fields like title, description at the same time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use $push and $set in your call.

Comment: Done if you need more help say!